# Filtering or restricting Google-Oauth2 login to a set of users in Django using Python Social Auth

Tags: python, regex, django, google-oauth, python-social-auth

Ive been able to filter them out through domain, but if i want to use some regex for further filtering. Can i do that? I've been researching a lot lately; and I thought making a partial pipeline was the solution. But due to poor docs; I wasn't able to a achieve my goal. 
Adding a middleware also didn't help as the login process completely overrides my added function.
I wanted to do something like this.

middleware.py

```
class MyMiddleware(SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if type(exception) == AuthForbidden:
            return render(request, "app/needlogin.html", {})

    def process_request(self,request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            name = request.user.username.split('@')[0]
            roll=[]
            for i in name:
                if i.isdigit():
                    roll.append(i)
            if int(roll[1])<3:
                auth_logout(request)
                return render(request,"app/notlogin.html",{})
            # else:
                # return render(request, "app/needlogin.html",{})
```

The problem is it processes every request and not specifically Login request. Also It doesn't work. Please point out where I am going wrong.

Help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a pipeline function for that, something simple as this should do the trick:

```
from social.exceptions import AuthForbidden

def email_check(strategy, details, *args, **kwargs):
    if not is_valid_email(details.get(email)):
        raise AuthForbidden(strategy.backend)
```

Then stick this function after `'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',` entry, like this:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'import.path.to.email_check',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. So it was working as it should be. I wasn't testing the correct condition.